# Editor visual bug when getting close to object

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Hi I have a problem with my objects and is that they began glitching when I zoom on them a little bit, it's like a kind of "bugged X-Ray" even though I don't have enabled any x-ray options like wireframe or the x-ray itself (Alt+z)

[image]
In this image the object looks good (with a face in the other side selected)

[image]
But when I zoom a little bit, it glitches and begins to appear some faces from the other side

[image]
In this image again, everything looks ok

[image]
But when I zoom, the faces began glitching